# System.threading.timer callbacks irregular

Tags: multithreading

I am working on highly threaded C# windows service, where we have used System.threading.timer to notify client after certain time.

When we have less timer initialize it worked fine for me, but when we used more timers which invokes callback method we were not getting the callback method after predefined time.

We were getting callbacks irregularly..

Thanks...

Comment: You write 'client': Are the notifications sent over network or do you just mean 'client of the service'?